# How to tell if 24 hours has passed with only time and no dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql query for flights that returns this:

```
first_scheduled_departure_time | second_scheduled_departure_time | first_scheduled_arrival_time | second_scheduled_arrival_time
--------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------
 08:25:00                       | 08:20:00                        | 10:10:00                     | 12:10:00
 07:55:00                       | 09:40:00                        | 09:40:00                     | 11:50:00
 13:50:00                       | 07:55:00                        | 15:35:00                     | 09:40:00
 10:05:00                       | 08:25:00                        | 11:50:00                     | 10:10:00
 08:20:00                       |                                 | 12:10:00                     |
```

The point is to figure out if the 2 legs of a flight take more than 24 hours.

The first row clearly takes more than 24 hours. The first leg leaves at 08:25:00 and then arrives at 10:10:00 but then the next leg leaves at 08:20:00 and then lands at 12:10:00.... that clearly takes 24 hours. How can I remove that row if needed?

Can I just see if the `first_scheduled_departure_time` is in between the second timestamps?

Comment: what sgdb are you using?

Comment: But a departure time later than arrival time could *also* mean more than 24hrs (arrives Monday at 9AM, departs Tuesday at 2PM). There's no getting around it: Your time columns need to be datetime. Fix the schema and data rather than hack together a flaky query.

Comment: That's not a possibility. That data is out of my control

Comment: Depends on what preconditions you have. If you don't have any dates in your db, must apply some assumptions, for instance that  a sequence like "9:00 - 15:00   17:00 - 21:00" means, that 15:00 and 17:00 are in fact on the same day. If you cannot be sure of this, there might be a week between those timestamps. And there is no way of determining how long this actually takes

Comment: If you can make the above mentioned assumption you can calculate 3 timespans ie duration of first leg, duration of  second leg, time between them. just substract the respective timestamps (for instance `first_arrival - first_start`  or `second_start - first_arrival'), and if the duration gets negative add 24hours. Then add all 3 timespans and check if their sum > 24 hours.

Comment: hmmm let me think about it. Want ot write a more fleshed answer and I'll upvote it?

Comment: does this properly handle midnight crossing?

Comment: Are the times all relative to one timezone or are they in local time?

Comment: Impossible to answer without any date and timezone information. Don't forget daylight savings, that also has an impact on your calculation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question can not be answered: Without a date and without a time zone it's impossible to calculate the difference. Is the flight 11 hours or is it 12 hours? Did DST kick in or not?

Answer (score -1):

First, with no date in the timestamps (and no timezones) there is no way to tell for sure how many days have passed. So, considering that, I will provide the best answer possible with the information available.

Basically, what we can determine are only the most obvious cases where for sure 24 hours have been exceeded and remove them from the results.

Here is the trick: if the time at the end of any leg is less than the previous, it is happening in the next day (for example departure at 11pm arrival 1am).

Sum all the legs and you get the total time consumed between the first departure and second arrival.

Here is how to implement it:

```
WITH FlightDurations AS (
  SELECT
    first_scheduled_departure_time,
    second_scheduled_departure_time,
    first_scheduled_arrival_time,
    second_scheduled_arrival_time,
    -- Calculate Total Duration in Hours
    (
      -- Leg 1 Duration
      CASE
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_departure_time)
        THEN (86400 + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_departure_time))
        ELSE (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_departure_time))
      END
      +
      -- Layover Duration
      CASE
        WHEN second_scheduled_departure_time IS NULL OR first_scheduled_arrival_time IS NULL
        THEN 0
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time)
        THEN (86400 + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time))
        ELSE (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM first_scheduled_arrival_time))
      END
      +
      -- Leg 2 Duration
      CASE
        WHEN second_scheduled_arrival_time IS NULL OR second_scheduled_departure_time IS NULL
        THEN 0
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_arrival_time) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time)
        THEN (86400 + EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_arrival_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time))
        ELSE (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_arrival_time) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM second_scheduled_departure_time))
      END
    ) / 3600 AS TotalDurationInHours
  FROM flights
)

SELECT *
FROM FlightDurations
WHERE TotalDurationInHours <= 24;
```

Result:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| first_scheduled_departure_time | second_scheduled_departure_time | first_scheduled_arrival_time | second_scheduled_arrival_time | TotalDurationInHours |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
| 07:55:00                      | 09:40:00                        | 09:40:00                     | 11:50:00                      | 3.9167             |
| 13:50:00                      | 07:55:00                        | 15:35:00                     | 09:40:00                      | 19.8333            |
| 08:20:00                      | null                           | 12:10:00                     | null                          | 3.8333             |
+------------------------------+---------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/kuiWeXEh

Comment: And you know this because you are certain all the times are relative to the same timezone?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it would be strange if a database with only times and no dates have different timezones and no notations. It is the best guess with information available, also notice that it is the minimum time duration, as there might be more than a day of difference in each interval.

Comment: It is equally strange that flight information would not have date information. As of now you are making a big assumption not supported by evidence.

Comment: You are right, and it is a valid point. But you are assuming a problem that is not in the scope of the question. 

The question is, how to detect if 24 hours have passed, with only the time and no dates. So, the challenge here is to determine if there is an obvious match of more than 24 hours, and remove of the rows. 

While I understand there are exceptions in real life, again, it is not in the scope of what was asked, and you are adding more problems to the original question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I will edit my answer to make these facts more clear anyway